Problem with the CMT2220LS receiver receiving a signal when transmitting a signal from the EO7-M1010D
I decided to play around with radio modules and make myself a remote control. I use Raspberry pi 5 as a transmitter, the EO7-M1010D transceiver is connected to it via SPI, and cc1101-python is used as a library. To begin with, I want to limit myself to only sending an analog signal (zeros and ones). I have a Raspberry Pi PICO as the receiving side, with an installed radio receiver - CMT2220LS (it seems to work at 433 frequency). The essence of the problem is that the receiver refuses to catch anything
I tried (rather stupidly, but still) to increase the number of sent signals on the transmitter, but it did not help. Maybe someone knows what the problem is? Thanks in advance for your answer
PICO code
from machine import Pin
import utime

class SignalReceiver:
    def __init__(self, pin_number):
        self.sig_pin = Pin(pin_number, Pin.IN)
        self.sig_pin.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_RISING | Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=self.signal_callback)
        self.last_value = -1

    def signal_callback(self, pin):
        
        current_value = pin.value()
        if current_value != self.last_value:

            print(f"Current signal value: {current_value}")
            self.last_value = current_value

def main():
    receiver = SignalReceiver(28)
    while True:
        utime.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


RPI5 code
import time

import cc1101

with cc1101.CC1101() as transceiver:
    transceiver.set_base_frequency_hertz(433.92e6)
    print(transceiver)


    binary_message = b'\x01' * 10
    while True:
        try:
            transceiver.transmit(binary_message)
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass


I just connected the transmitter that came with the receiver to the RPI5, and I was surprised... Literally nothing, the picture has not changed, the signal is still not received.
I went further, connected the receiver to Arduino, configured the signal reception using the rc-switch library sketch, but still there were no changes. Now I’ll try to connect the receiver to RPI5, and the transmitter to PICO (maybe it will work)

By the way, I just remembered, I tried to receive and transmit a signal from one Raspberry board, with just the same receiver and transmitter (which are from CMT2220LS), and then everything worked and was received
